# creating scalar function cannot return data

Tags: sql

hi  make function with simple parameter

```
create function test (@takesID as int)
returns nvarchar(50)
as
begin
  declare @num int
  set @num = 6
  SELECT        ID, Description_mm
  FROM            dbo.Win_Products
  WHERE        (ID = @takesID)
  return @num
end
```

gets message as:

```
Msg 444, Level 16, State 2, Procedure test, Line 7
```

Select statements included within a function cannot return data to a client.

please help, thank you for your precious time, really appreciate.

sonu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you trying to return ? The Description_mm or the hard-coded @num ?

If you are trying to return the description try...

```
create function test (@takesID as int)
returns nvarchar(50)
as
begin
  declare @Description_mm nvarchar(50);
  SELECT        @Description_mm =  Description_mm
  FROM            dbo.Win_Products
  WHERE        (ID = @takesID);
  return @Description_mm;
end
```

Comment: That's perfect thank you so much, i understand we use create and use function to avoid repetation but can you explain the parameters - like next to function name ( @takes..) what is that for and how to determine what to put there and also  why we declare  again after begin- what is that for. Await your reply.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the issue is exactly as what the error message states, you cannot return a result set in a scalar function.

So you need to at least insert the values into a temp table, or not have the select at all.

```
create function test (@takesID as int)
returns nvarchar(50)
as
begin
  declare @num int
  set @num = 6

  return @num
end
```

Comment: That's perfect thank you so much, i understand we use create and use function to avoid repetation but can you explain the parameters - like next to function name ( @takes..) what is that for and how to determine what to put there and also why we declare again after begin- what is that for. Await your reply